# using the same string of command in windows task scheduler does not work

Tags: cmd.exe, windows-task-scheduler, task-scheduler

So when i use the following command in a CMD window `warp-cli disconnect && taskkill -im "Cloudflare WARP.exe" && cd "C:\Program Files\Cloudflare\Cloudflare WARP" && "Cloudflare WARP.exe"` everything works as expected but when i use this in task scheduler like so:
[image: TASK SCHEDULER WINDOW]

Nothing happens.

Under the `Add arguments` section I use the following command `/k warp-cli disconnect && taskkill -im "Cloudflare WARP.exe" && cd "C:\Program Files\Cloudflare\Cloudflare WARP" && "Cloudflare WARP.exe"`

any help would be appreciated

Comment: if you make a `cloudflare.bat` file and fill it with `warp-cli disconnect && taskkill -im "Cloudflare WARP.exe" && cd "C:\Program Files\Cloudflare\Cloudflare WARP" && "Cloudflare WARP.exe"` and set the task scheduler to run that instead, does it work?

Comment: @Narzard saving it as `.bat` file works but i would not prefer that.

Comment: try wrapping the entire thing aside form  `/k` in double quotes. `/k "warp-cli disconnect && taskkill -im "Cloudflare WARP.exe" && cd "C:\Program Files\Cloudflare\Cloudflare WARP" && "Cloudflare WARP.exe""`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest setting the `Start in` as the path to the warp application executables rather than relying on the `cd` command to change to that directory so at execution, it is already there.

Since the program you are starting is explicitly defined with the full path to `cmd.exe` setting `start in` to the warp directory should help you resolve the problem.

### Task Scheduler Configuration

- **Program/Script:**

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
```

- **Add arguments:**

```
/k start "" "warp-cli" disconnect && taskkill -im "Cloudflare WARP.exe" && "Cloudflare WARP.exe"
```

- **Start in:**

```
"C:\Program Files\Cloudflare\Cloudflare WARP"
```

---

### Supporting Resource

- [Why is "start in" needed for Windows scheduled tasks?](https://serverfault.com/questions/426519/why-is-start-in-needed-for-windows-scheduled-tasks)

Comment: This also gives the same behaviour..nothing...unfortunately

Comment: Later I tried this command in the `arguments` section with the `start in` column blank:  `/k timeout 2 && warp-cli disconnect && timeout 2 && taskkill -im "Cloudflare WARP.exe" && timeout 2 && cd "C:\Program Files\Cloudflare\Cloudflare WARP" && timeout 2 && "Cloudflare WARP.exe"`, but this only workes till `warp-cli disconnect` after which it does not work.

Comment: @AwesomeVk47 I just updated my answer for add argurments to use [start](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html) and the syntax of `start "" warp-cli disconnect` then it goes to taskkill, etc. See if that helps, otherwise [Call](https://ss64.com/nt/call.html) may work if you play with it some instead.

Comment: unfoertunately that did not work either..and as far as i can see `call` command is used to start another batch file right?

Comment: @AwesomeVk47 See if that edit I just now made makes a difference. I assume not but forgot double quote around program after title empty double quote for `start "" "warp-cli" disconnect`. Call or Start both can call other batch files or other executable files too. I'm not familiar with the warp tools you are using and I do not have it installed, but wonder if not using `warp-cli disconnect` at all and removing it and using `taskkill /f /im "Cloudflare WARP.exe"` alone then some time out would work. Where is `warp-cli` located, the same folder as `Cloudflare WARP.exe` or not?

Comment: Yes `warp-cli.exe` is in the same location as `Cloudflare WARP.exe`

Comment: @AwesomeVk47 Did you try the latest updating use `start`? Since all the executable/binary files you are executing are in the same directory, then the start in scheduled task directory should having the need to not have to call any of those full excplicit path wise. You can throw in the timeouts anywhere, just use the example in the latest update as I defined for the calling of the warp executables. Maybe the disconnect is not even needed if you taskkill the process and you can take it out of the loop and get the desired result.